# Advantages of change Hybrid Code(Objective-C and Swift) to only Swift Code

Tags: swift

Title is what I want to ask. I have Objective-C code and Swift code both with bridge-header. But Is there any advantage to change code to only swift2.2 code? If it is reasonable, I want to change. Thank you in advance
(Need some proven data to assure me) :)

Comment: Ultimately, it will depend on the scale and available resources of your project, if it is feasible/worth the effort to port all legacy code to Swift. The benefits given below by @AMomchilov should help you decide. You have to balance pros and cons.

Comment: Thank you for your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Swift code runs faster.

  - Objective C methods are always dynamically dispatched, whereas in many cases, Swift method calls can be optimized to be statically dispatched.
  - Swift provides stronger type information to the compiler, allowing for more aggressive optimisation
- Swift code is better for developers

  - More concise. Objective-C is well known for its boiler-plate
  - "Fun" to write
  - More informed type information provided by the IDE
- Swift code is safer

  - Optionals eliminate a whole class of `nil` messaging errors
  - Swift's superior type system, including generics, require less unsafe casting.

Comment: Hello Thank you for your answer. I know Swift code is safer and better too code. What I want to know is "Is there any statistical data Only swift code is faster than hybrid code" I  will change my question thank you

Comment: Well any parts in Objective C will be slower than their Swift counter parts. This may not have any noticeable effect, depending on what those parts are.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will keep in mind your answer :) Great!